# I cannot initiate a Principal in KeycloakAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

I have simple application in Spring to login using Keycloak Adapter.

This is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleAdminRequest(Principal principal, Model model) {
    KeycloakPrincipal pr = (KeycloakPrincipal) principal.getUserPrincipal();
    return "admin";
}
```

Now i have cast problem:

```
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal
```

Can someone tell my why this happen? And how i can resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similar problem by changing the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When the scope is **provided** there are no conflicts with the libs on the server.